# Require HTTPS in C# Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How can I require HTTPS for my C# apicontrollers?

I know that I can add a RequireHTTPSAttribute like this here : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api but this just adds "HTTPS Required" to the response.

What I would rather have it do, is output json on screen that says, "HTTPS Required" instead of it just being on what of the response headers.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

This is what I came up with, is there a more elegant way to do it, so I have less repetition of code.

```
        ResultWrapper<Temp> wrapper = new ResultWrapper<Temp>(Request);

        if (Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            wrapper.Error = "Https is Required";
        }
        else
        {
            wrapper.RequestUrl = Request.RequestUri.ToString();

            wrapper.Results.Url = "http://www.google.com";
        }

        return wrapper;
```

**Second Edit**

I found a better way, you can edit the Content stream being sent back in the response and send back any class you want serialized as Json, like this :

```
 Content = new StringContent(Json.Encode(wrapper))
```

Comment: can you implement the custom behavior after detecting if the protocol is use is HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be an attribute, but in every controller method, I don't want to have to check if the request is HTTPS unless I truly have to..

Comment: you could use a filter (or a reusable method) to isolate this check in just one place =)

Comment: Right, I have what I call a result wrapper, which is returned for each of my API calls.  One of the properties is ErrorMessage, which is where I would ideally like to put the "https is required", I guess the only way to do that is check the https in the controller.  Do you have the line of code necessary to do this?

Comment: Nevermind found it : if (request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)

Comment: You can use HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection

Comment: @MarceloBezerra Only if you are running in ASP.Net IIS. I would advise against using `HttpContext` in Web API, as you can also self host Web API, and that would break.

Comment: @Aron and Marcelo, look at my edit please, do you think there's a more elegant way to code it?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/09/implementing-requirehttps-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx

Comment: What the example shows (returning 403, with error message) is the standard way of saying SSL is required (ASP.NET/IIS convention). You can do whatever you like but I don't see a benefit.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple filter for Web API yourself to enforce HTTPS. Since you are using Web API 2, create an authentication filter like this.

```
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, 
                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (context.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            context.ActionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(
                                    System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context,
                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```